# How to keep track of sockets in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I am trying to keep track of all tcp connections that are made in my server and store it in an array.

My problem begins when some connection is closed, in this situation **I should delete it** from my array but I can't do it. Can anyone help me? How do I delete a socket that is stored in my array?

```
var net = require("net");

function Server(port) {
    var self = this;

    this.conections = [];

    this.server = net.createServer(function(socket) {     
        self.conections.push(socket);   //storing the socket in the array             
    })

    this.server.listen(port);
    console.log("TCP Server created on port: "+ port);
}

module.exports = Server;
```

Comment: each socket will issue an `end` event that you could catch and update your array with.

Comment: I understand that, but I still have to run over my array to match the current closed connection with its own reference in the array. Any ideia on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking for a while I realized that I could give an ID to each socket, this way I can monitor each new connection in an array and delete it in case the connection is lost.

```
var net = require("net");

function Server(port) {
    var self = this;

    this.connections = [];
    this.connectionsId = 0;

    this.server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
        socket.id = self.connectionsId++;    
        self.connections.push(socket);   //storing the socket in the array             
    })

    //Event that is always trigger when the connection is ended
    socket.on('close', function() {
         self.connections = self.connections.filter(function(conn) {
              return conn.id !== socket.id;
         });
    });

    this.server.listen(port);
    console.log("TCP Server created on port: "+ port);
}

module.exports = Server;
```

Hope it helps somebody!